# keplerr can't get Web development tools

Tags: eclipse

I installed http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-standard-43/keplerr. I need to work with Dynamic web project but i can't create one. How can i add it? Isn't it possible to add the functionality from the market place?

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftwcreprj.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard functionality (i.e. Eclipse projects, functionality available in other bundles) can be installed via `Help > Install New Software...`, select the appropriate update site ("Kepler").